# Bitwise- code interpretation

Tags: c++, arrays, bitwise-operators

I wanted to ask for help in interpreting a code in C ++.

```
#define bit(b) (1 << (b)) // I do not understand the operation.
#define contains(n, b) ((n) & bit(b)) // I do not understand the operation.

 #define MAXV 26

using namespace std;


vector<int> vars;
int deps[MAXV];

string curr;

   void printOrderings(int used, int usedSize) {
  if(usedSize == (int) vars.size()) {
    cout << curr << endl; return;
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < (int) vars.size(); i++) {
    int v = vars[i];
    if(!contains(used, v) && ((used & deps[v]) == deps[v])) {
      curr.push_back(v + 'a');
      printOrderings(used | bit(v), usedSize + 1);
      curr.erase(curr.end() - 1);
    }
  }
}


int main() {
    int tc = 0;
    string line;

    while(getline(cin, line)) {
        if(tc++)
            cout << endl;

        vars.clear();
        for( int i = 0 ; i < (int) line.length() ; i += 2 ) {
            vars.push_back( line[i] - 'a' );
            deps[ line[i] - 'a' ] = 0;
        }
        sort( vars.begin(), vars.end() );

        getline(cin, line);

        for( int i = 0 ; i < (int) line.length() ; i += 4 )
            deps[ line[ i + 2 ] - 'a' ] |= bit( line[ i ] - 'a' ); //I do not understand the operation.

        printOrderings(0, 0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For a problem where the input would be something like:

a b f g

a b b f

v w x y z

v y x v z v w v

I do not understand how *Defines* works (bit, contains) that use bitwise. And how *deps* array works.

Can you give me a hand?

The code is a possible solution to the problem: [https://uva.onlinejudge.org/external/1/p124.pdf](http://t%20is%20a%20possible%20solution%20to%20the%20problem:%20https://uva.onlinejudge.org/external/1/p124.pdf)

Thank you.

Comment: The #define macros are macro functions.  They are evil, and in C++ there are usually much better alternatives.  The first means `int bit(int pos) { return 1 << pos; }` to return an int with a particular bit set.  The second means `bool contains(int num, int b) { return n & bit(b); }`.

Comment: contains is not referenced in the sample

Comment: @IlanKeshet edit post

Comment: @Eljay Not exactly.  The `bit(b)` in here acts like a function returning a `char` where the `b`th bit is set - `bit(4)` would return `0000 1000` assuming a char takes 8 bits. The `contains(n,b)` in the code above returns an `int`. Its function is to check whether the `b`th bit is set in `n`, returning `0` if the bit is not set and `!= 0` if the bit is set.

Comment: It would be great if the code was compileable... How are `vars`, `deps`, `curr`  and the likes declared?

Comment: @MichaelBeer post edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#define bit(b) (1 << (b))
```

This will "return" (" because its technically just a macro) a 32-bit integer where only the "b"th bit is 1 while the rest is 0

Imagine a 32-bit number format in binary like this:

> 0000 0000 0000 0000 (dec 0)

Now what bit(b) really does is shift

> 0000 0000 0000 0001  (dec 1)

"b" times to the left.

so if we do bit(4) we will get

> 0000 0000 0001 0000 (dec 16)

```
#define contains(n, b) ((n) & bit(b)) // I do not understand the operation.
```

This will, by compiler default return either bit(b) or 0 depending on if n has the "b"th bit from the right switched on. This will mean that if you try contain(15,2), where in binary they look like this

> 0000 0000 0000 1111 (dec 15)
>   / 0000 0000 0000 0100 (dec 4 - 1 two times shifted to the left)

You can easily do binary operations like &,|,^ (AND, OR, XOR) by writing both numbers below each other, so 15 & 4 in binary would look like this:

```
0000 0000 0000 1111

0000 0000 0000 0100 &
__________________
0000 0000 0000 0100 (again, dec 4)
```

---

If you wonder how defines in C/C++ work they depend on which compiler you use, on Microsoft Visual C++ compilers they get interpreted as just copy pasting the "defined" content into where the macro is used, on linux based compilers they normally do some error checking (and I had my trouble with them on a small level), but work almost similar to the previously mentioned window based one.

---

Now the "deps" part is tricky since we don't know what this is actually for. You have to describe it a bit more. But using your string "a b f g" on

```
for( int i = 0 ; i < (int) line.length() ; i += 4 )
    deps[ line[ i + 2 ] - 'a' ] |= bit( line[ i ] - 'a' );
```

will give out these lines

```
deps[line[0+2]-'a'] |= bit(line[0]-'a']
deps[line[4+2]-'a'] |= bit(line[4]-'a']



deps['b'-'a'] |= bit('a'-'a']
deps['g'-'a'] |= bit('f'-'a']



deps[1] |= bit(0)
deps[6] |= bit(5)


deps[1] |= 1
deps[6] |= 32 //remember 0000 0000 0010 0000
```

and since all deps[] items have been set to 0 before, in this example all array items are 0 except 1 and 6, which are set to 1 and 32.

|= does nothing else than set the bits that are 1 on the right side also 1 on the left side of the operator

I hope this helped, I seriously see no reason to what this program should do but this should give you an insight of what is actually happening

Comment: The code is a possible solution to the problem: https://uva.onlinejudge.org/external/1/p124.pdf